# Getting error [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] Unknown database type point requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Laravel and I just added a new migration for increasing column size.
The first generated table has a column named `latlong` of type `Point`.
I can't modify any column size?

When I try to modify a column's size, I get the error below:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
> Unknown database type point requested,
> Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

Here are my migration files. First migration is for create a table `abc`

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::create('abc', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name', 20);
        $table->string('last_name', 20);
        $table->string('street', 100);
        $table->string('city', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('state', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('postal_code', 15);
        $table->string('mobile', 10)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
});   
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('ALTER TABLE abc ADD latlong POINT');

}
```

Second migration is for update column size

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::table('abc', function (Blueprint $table){
     $table->string('mobile', 20)->nullable()->change();
 });
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: May be `Point` is not supported by laravel check this answer to [fix this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220523/2815635)

Comment: yes, `Point` is the issue here.

Comment: if I use  `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('ALTER TABLE abc MODIFY mobile VARCHAR(20)');` 
then it's working fine for me. But I don't want to use this solution.

Answer (score 9):

In your migration, add the following function:

```
public function __construct()
{
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()
       ->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('point', 'string');
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest the Doctrine type should be "binary" not "string" for this. And note that this needs to be added to any migration that alters a table with a POINT column.

Answer (score 0):

If you suddenly get this problem on Symfony, try to delete the var folder to reset the cache, and execute the command one more time to see if it works.