# how to retrive records from MySQL with POINT datatype in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have `location` column in my table that is `POINT` datatype and I am trying to retrieve the locations with specific longitude and latitude, but I get empty collection every time I try to.

migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBranchesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->point('location');
            $table->spatialIndex('location');
            $table->foreignId('supplier_id')->constrained();
            $table->boolean('is_main')->default(false);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('branches');
    }
}
```

model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Casts\PointCasting;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;

class Branch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SpatialTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
      'location',
      'supplier_id',
    ];

    protected $spatialFields = [
        'location'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
      'location' => PointCasting::class
    ];
```

PointCasting.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class PointCasting implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
      return [
          'Lat' => $value->getLat(),
          'Lng' =>$value->getLng()
      ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return new Point($value['lat'], $value['lon']);
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
Branch::where('location', new Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point(50.1, 40.01))->get();
Branch::where('location', new Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point(40.01, 50.1))->get();
Branch::where('location', [50.01, 40.01])->get();
Branch::where('location', [40.01, 50.1])->get();
```

and the package I am using is : [grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial](https://packagist.org/packages/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial)

the data I am trying to retrieve are there because when I try using phpmyadmin it appears:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel model with POINT/POLYGON etc. using DB::raw expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360969/laravel-model-with-point-polygon-etc-using-dbraw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

u can use scope exists on  `SpatialTrait`

it calls `equals`
and also there is alot of other scopes could help to

Available scopes:

- `distance($geometryColumn, $geometry, $distance)`
- `distanceExcludingSelf($geometryColumn, $geometry, $distance)`
- `distanceSphere($geometryColumn, $geometry, $distance)`
- `distanceSphereExcludingSelf($geometryColumn, $geometry, $distance)`
- `comparison($geometryColumn, $geometry, $relationship)`
- `within($geometryColumn, $polygon)`
- `crosses($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `contains($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `disjoint($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `equals($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `intersects($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `overlaps($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `doesTouch($geometryColumn, $geometry)`
- `orderBySpatial($geometryColumn, $geometry, $orderFunction, $direction = 'asc')`
- `orderByDistance($geometryColumn, $geometry, $direction = 'asc')`
- `orderByDistanceSphere($geometryColumn, $geometry, $direction = 'asc')`

*Note that behavior and availability of MySQL spatial analysis functions differs in each MySQL version (cf. [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html)).*